# Why my fs.readFileSync does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Why does this code not work?
If I comment
    fs.readFileSync('file.html');
the code works and it creates the file 'file.html'
But if I uncomment it the fs.writeFileSync does not work, and the program crashes with the error:

> fs.js:427
>     return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
>                    ^
>   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'file.html'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
>       at Object. (/home/pedro/startupEngineering/hw3/Bitstarter/testrestler.js:15:6)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:901:3

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


var fs = require('fs');
var rest = require('restler');

var restlerHtmlFile = function(Url) {
  rest.get(Url).on('complete', function(result) {
   fs.writeFileSync('file.html',result);
  });
};

if(require.main == module) {
  restlerHtmlFile('http://obscure-refuge-7370.herokuapp.com/');
  fs.readFileSync('file.html');
}

else {
 exports.checkHtmlFile = checkHtmlFile;
}
```

Comment: `no such file or directory 'file.html'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var restlerHtmlFile = function(Url) {
  rest.get(Url).on('complete', function(result) {
   fs.writeFileSync('file.html',result);
  });
};

if(require.main == module) {
  restlerHtmlFile('http://obscure-refuge-7370.herokuapp.com/');
  fs.readFileSync('file.html');
}
```

to

```
var restlerHtmlFile = function(Url) {
  rest.get(Url).on('complete', function(result) {
   fs.writeFileSync('file.html',result);
   fs.readFileSync('file.html');
  });
};

if(require.main == module) {
  restlerHtmlFile('http://obscure-refuge-7370.herokuapp.com/');
}
```

Second parameter to `rest.get(Url).on` is an asynchronous call back function, which will be called when `complete` occurs and only then the file gets created. But you are reading the file, even before the `complete` occurs. Thats why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't write the file until the `complete` event fires, but you try to read from it immediately.

Since it doesn't yet exist, you get an exception, which you don't catch, so the program exits before the `complete` event fires and the file is written.

You need to move the code that tries to read from the file inside the event handler that writes the file.